# VHDL unexpected behaviour of XNOR for std_logic_vector

Tags: vhdl, logical-operators

I have a series of 25 64bit std_logic_vectors in my structural VHDL code. These should always be identical and I want to test if there are any faults which flip a bit. My code looks like this:

```
outX <= mt1_op XNOR mr2_op XNOR mt3_op XNOR .... XNOR mt25_op;
```

This gives me no errors and synthesises fine, but when I simulate it in ISim, the XNOR operation does not seem to be working. I expect all 1s or the occasional 0 if there is a fault, but the final output signal, outX, simply has the same value as all of the input signals. I won't bother stating the entire 64bit vector but as an unsigned int it resolves to 7776. All of the input vectors are the same - 7776 - and when I XNOR them all together, I get an answer of 7776.

I suspect that the problem might be caused by the XNOR operations being applied one at a time, i.e.

```
OutX <= (mt1_op XNOR mt2_op XNOR(mt3_op XNOR(mt4_op XNOR( ..... )))))))));
```

which will not give the desired behaviour.

Does anyone have an idea how I can get the behaviour that I want? i.e. if all 25 vectors are identical, give me all 1s or where there are differences, give me a 0. ??

Thanks

Tom

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`XNOR` expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XNOR_gate) is working just fine:

```
'0' XNOR '0' XNOR ... XNOR '0' = '0'  -- For 25 XNOR '0's
'1' XNOR '1' XNOR ... XNOR '1' = '1'  -- For 25 XNOR '1's
```

So the expression will return the argument vector if the same vector is given 25 times to `XNOR`.

To check if all vectors are identical you can do:

```
or_all <= mt1_op OR mt2_op OR ... OR mt25_op;    
and_all <= mt1_op AND mt2_op AND ... AND mt25_op; 
identical <= or_all = and_all;  -- Boolean as resulting type
```

And for resulting type as `std_logic`

```
identical_std_logic <= '1' when (and_all = or_all) else '0';
```

Comment: '0' XOR '0' = '0' and XNOR should be the complimentary function?

Comment: Yes `'0' XNOR '0' = '1'`, and `'0' XOR '0' = '0'`; answer is updated with reference to Wikipedia XNOR description.  Note that the `'0' XNOR '0' XNOR ... XNOR '0' = '0'` is only true for odd number of `'0's`.

Comment: That last line "identical <= or_all = and_all;"  - what does that do? XST doesn't like it. I get error message on synthesis: "found '0' definitions of operator "=", cannot determine exact overloaded matching definition for "=""

Comment: The `or_all = and_all` is just plain compare, but the resulting type is `boolean`, and not `std_logic` as you may have declared as type for `identical`.

Comment: I ended up using conditional assignment statements rather than the boolean comparator, but otherwise that's done the trick very nicely, thanks!